# About a sequential list in python

Tags: python

if my list is in the following format:

```
a=[1,3,4,5,8,10]
```

How can I show that the elements are not increasing by 1? In other words, if my list is

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

the function should say that it is sequential i.e. each element is greater than the previous element by one. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not here to do your work for you, though we're happy to help if you've tried some things and run into problems. Show us your code and let us know what's going wrong and you'll probably get a helpful answer right away.

Comment: These reasonable comments, followed by 5 answers below... Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> a=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> all(i==j for i,j in enumerate(a, a[0]))
True

>>> a=[1,3,4,5,8,10]
>>> 
>>> all(i==j for i,j in enumerate(a, a[0]))
False
```

Comment: @6502, it was rubbish. I've got an improved version

Comment: +1: compact and avoids re-evaluating `a [0]`. It would complain with floats but the OP is consifering integers..

Answer (score 1):

One simple way to do the testing is

```
if all(x[i] == x[0]+i for i in range(1, len(x))):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip` and `set`:

```
def check_sequential(a):
    return set([p - q for p, q in zip(a[1:], a)]) == {1}

print check_sequential([1,3,4,5,8,10])
print check_sequential([1,2,3,4,5])
```

Output:

```
False
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Use numpy.

Differentiate it

Use Max.

Comment: Better check `min` too in case the sequence isn't increasing

Answer (score 0):

For short lists, you can just create a sequential range yourself and compare them

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> a == range(a[0], a[-1] + 1) # in Python3, you need list(range(...))
True
>>> a = [1,3,4,5,8,10]
>>> a == range(a[0], a[-1] + 1)
False
```